# extending an instantiation of a non-static class to a static class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, groovy

I am trying to build a static class structure, and I want to convert an object instantiation of a non-static class to a static class of this static class structure, not as an object but as a class

I've tried things like

```
public final class Client {
  public final static Widget FundSummary = new Widget("url")
    {
     public class FundSummary extends Widget{
          public final static Field FUNDNAMELIST = new Field("xpath", this)
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public final class Client {
   public class FundSummary extends new Widget("xpath")//this is not the right syntax, but it's what I want to achieve
   {
   } 
}
```

but havent been able to get my end goal of calling this static class using

```
Client.FundSummary.FUNDNAMELIST.getPermissions() //works
```

and

```
Client.FundSummary.getPermissions() //does not work
```

Here are the non-static classes

```
public class Element {
    public final Integer id
    public final String xpath
    public final String nameUI

    public Element(xpath, nameUI=null, id=null) {
        this.xpath = xpath
        this.id = id
        this.nameUI = nameUI
    }
}


public class Widget extends Element  {

    public final permissions
    public Widget(xpath, nameUI=null, id=null, def permissions= null) {

        super(xpath, nameUI, id)
        this.permissions = permissions
    }
    public String getURL() {
    }
    public String getPermissions(User user, int entityID = GlobalVariable.clientID) {
    }
}

public class Field extends Element{
    public final Widget widget
    public final permissions
    public Field(xpath, Widget, nameUI=null, id=null, def permissions=null) {

        super(xpath, nameUI, id)
        this.permissions = permissions
        this.widget = Widget
    }
    public String getPermissions(User user, int entityID = GlobalVariable.clientID) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is seriously weird code. A class defined inside an anonymous class... What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm building an automation framework and this static class structure will carry the xpath location of elements and will be able to provide permissions for widgets or fields depending on a given user

Comment: There is no definition for `widget_Non_Static_Function()` in the code sample, but presumably that is a non-static method defined on the `FundSummary` class. If so, it is correct that you cannot call `Client.FundSummary.widget_Non_Static_Function()` because you need an instance of `FundSummary` in order to invoke a non-static method.

Comment: Also, please see this: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code should _"provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem"_.

Comment: @kaan appologies, I have updated the description. please look again